# Why can't I put this static mesh statue inside this static mesh jar in UE4?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am currently working on GameDev Udemy course: Unreal Engine C++ Developer: Learn C++ and Make Video Games, and I am on the Building Escape module. While trying to build my own level, I have ran into a problem with collision between two static meshes. I am trying to hide the golden hooded statue mesh inside one of the jar assets, but whenever I hit play, the physics collides with each other and it goes crazy. I have tried adjusting the mass in kg, generate overlap feature, and the collision presets in Unreal, but it's still not working. I can pick up the object fine when it's out of the jar, but when it is in there, it sticks to the jar and I cant take just the statue out. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not familiar with unreal, but what does the collision mesh of the jar look like? Does it actually have an "inside"? Or is the collision simplified, as if the jar has a lid?

Comment: The jar and the lid are two different assets, I have simulated physics on those and the statue I would like to place in it. In Unreal's Visibility Collision view mode, all the assets that have simulated physics in are green if that helps.